# Mutlilingual support for an already build up APK

Tags: android, ios

I am facing a serious issue here. I built an android and iOS application. Now after I developed it completely and it is running seamlessly, I want it to be multilingual(both android and iOS). Is there any simplest method which I can use now to make both my android and iOS apps multilingual now. The .apk and .ipa files have already been prepared and the project is complete. Please help!!!!

Comment: It's easy to provide multi-lingual support in Android... I would be surprised if it wasn't equally easy in iOS. Obviously, you'll need to update the apps afterward... you can't use the apk or ipa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify your .apk and .ipa files to be multilingual. I mean, theoretically it's possible but it would be ludicrously difficult. If you are stuck with the .apk and .ipa files you have, then your task is extremely difficult, sorry.

You can modify the android and iOS projects (I am assuming they are separate projects) to provide multiple language versions of the resource files where your user text and images are stored, assuming that you correctly stored all text and images which get displayed to the user in resource files/folders.

For Android, see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

For IOS, see http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014.

Comment: Why can't they be modified?  make the changes, rebuild and release as an update.  What's the problem?

Comment: When you said that you have an apk, i thought you meant you want to modify the apk directly instead of making the changes to the project and rebuilding. You can absolutely do that.

Comment: Have you had any problems so far in localizing your app? (That's the word for making an app multilingual)

Comment: I'll tell you clearly... My client gave me this app to develop and now I have completed the project and deployed the project but forgot to make it multilingual and now there are serious issues in which client wants it to be multilingual. How to make it multilingual now?

Comment: er, I have to correct something I said: localization is not the right word for translating an app into multiple languages. I've also corrected the android link in my answer.

Comment: Let's start with android: Do you have your user-facing text stored in resource files, as described @ http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html ? If so, it will be very simple to provide an french version of the text in the values-fr folder, to use an example from the tutorial I've just linked.

(The process for iOS is very similar, by the way)

Comment: Is your problem a technical one, in that you're not sure how to store multiple versions of your text for multiple languages? Or is it a linguistic one, where you need help doing translations?

Comment: Yes my problem is technical.

Comment: Then i hope the guide i linked to is helpful. Feel free to let me know if you have any problems with it.

Comment: Can I have your mail or skype id so that we could do a instant chat regarding dis

Comment: Nope, I'm not interested in providing that kind of help.

Comment: Ok so let's discuss it here.... I a non-techie... Just have a brief idea about using resources... Now my android and ios developer say that they will charge me 1000s of dollars to make these both APPs multilingual. They say that they will have to do lot of work on these Apps. I want to know can it be done easily. Or can a semi-techie guy like me can do on his own or not?

Comment: If you're not comfortable doing computer programming than doing this yourself is probably impossible. 

I can't tell you if the price your developers want to charge is reasonable, but perhaps you could ask them about sending you the text which needs to change, and having you do all the translation work? That could make the job much easier for them, and consequentially cheaper for you.

Here's another thought: If you own complete rights to the source code, you could try to hire someone else to do the translation work. It might not save you money though.

Comment: So, that means if I hire some new guy to recode these APPs for multilingual function then it would not be tough for new developer to add this functionality to these APPs.

Comment: And also I have one more thought, because now if I don't hire these previous guys again due to some revenge, can they do something to these APPs that they never get multilingual again in future or would require whole APPs to built up again? (Just for being at safe side)

Comment: It wouldn't be tough, but it might be tedious depending on how the app was written. As for the subject of the old app developers sabotaging the app, do you have full access and legal rights to the source code for the app? If you don't, then you are locked in with the current developers. In general, i recommend against throwing away an existing relationship unless absolutely necessary. There's always a chance it will go badly if you do.

Comment: However, Thanks a ton brother to enlighten me with your knowledge... I really appreciate your effort. Let me know if I could help you sometime.... My email id is sourabh.arya@accelortech.com